# Рисование дуги окружности

Tags: java

Есть метод для рисования дуги окружности (там ещё и переливание цвета от одного к другому на протяжении дуги есть), при маленьком радиусе отрисовывается всё нормально, но если задать слишком большой радиус появятся разрывы между каждым пикселем( и чем больше радиус, тем больше пустоты между каждым пикселем). Как исправить этот баг? Возможно надо сделать что-то по типу рисование прямой от одного пикселя до другого, но как это реализовать.

```
public static void drawCircleAcr(
        final GraphicsContext graphicsContext,
        final int x,final int y,
        final int radius,
        final Color startColor,
        final Color endColor,
        final int startAngle,final int arcAngle)
{

    final PixelWriter pixelWriter = graphicsContext.getPixelWriter();
    int angle, x1, y1;
    for(int i = startAngle; i < arcAngle; i ++)
    {
        angle = i;
        x1 = (int) Math.round(radius * cos(angle * PI / 180));
        y1 = (int) Math.round(radius * sin(angle * PI / 180));
        double fraction = (double)(i - startAngle) / (double)(arcAngle - startAngle); //отношение разницы между текущим углом и начальным углом дуги к разнице между начальным и конечным углами дуги
        Color color = interpolate(startColor, endColor, fraction);
        pixelWriter.setColor(x + x1, y + y1, color);

    }
}
```

Пример вызова с нормальной отрисовкой

```
Rasterization.drawCircleAcr(canvas.getGraphicsContext2D(), 100, 200, 50,Color.BLUE,Color.RED,0,100);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример вызова где наблюдается баг

```
Rasterization.drawCircleAcr(canvas.getGraphicsContext2D(), 100, 200, 300,Color.BLUE,Color.RED,0,100);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте, например, метод Брезенхэма для окружности (не тот, что для линий)

Comment: у вас angle - целое число, а значит, у вас по вертикали окружность состоит из 180 значений Y. Либо, что проще, на диаметрах больше 180 (условно) уменьшайте шаг градуса angle (не на 1 градус, а, например, 0.1). Либо, что предпочтительней, послушайте человека сверху.

Comment: @MBo я смог реализовать метод для рисования окружности Брезенхэма ( у меня параллельно рисуются 4 разные дуги и образуют целую окружность), но не могу понять как подогнать этот метод под рисование дуги от начального угла на окружности до конечного.

Comment: Вам нужно самостоятельно сделать растеризацию дуги, не пользуясь функциями графических библиотек, кроме "поставить точку"? Если примитива дуг нет, но есть кривые Безье, то дело будет проще. Если и этого нет, отрезки прямых рисуйте, как у вас в вопросе уже говорится. Если окружность уже рисуется, то можно плюнуть  на лишние расчётами, и выводить только точки в нужном диапазоне углов, а остальные игнорировать.

Comment: @MBo Да, я могу только поставить точку. Спасибо за ответы, буду пытаться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шаг угла обратно пропорционален радиусу:

```
public static void drawCircleAcr(
        final GraphicsContext graphicsContext,
        final double x, final double y,
        final double radius,
        final Color startColor,
        final Color endColor,
        final double startAngle, final double endAngle)
{

    final PixelWriter pixelWriter = graphicsContext.getPixelWriter();
    double step = (180 / PI) / radius;
    for(double angle = startAngle; angle < endAngle; angle += step)
    {
        double x1 = radius * cos(angle * PI / 180);
        double y1 = radius * sin(angle * PI / 180);
        double fraction = (angle - startAngle) / (endAngle - startAngle); //отношение разницы между текущим углом и начальным углом дуги к разнице между начальным и конечным углами дуги
        Color color = interpolate(startColor, endColor, fraction);
        pixelWriter.setColor((int)Math.round(x + x1), (int)Math.round(y + y1), color);
    }
}
```

**P.S.** Это не значит что [Брезенхэм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B0) плох. Он хорош, но сложен в программировании и отладке. А это решение решает вашу задачу, устроено просто, написано быстро.

Answer (score 1):

Измените подход. Не рисуйте точки на окружности, а рисуйте линию пиксел за пикселом. От пиксела у вас есть три направления, в которых можно двигаться, соотвественно, три следующих пикселя - выбирайте из них тот, который будет ближе к дуге окружности. Собственно, это и есть алгоритм Брезенхэма для окружности, [который хорошо описан в Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B0).

Это была моя первая графическая программа на ассемблере. Тогда не было Википедии, а возжно, и не было самого Брезенхэма :-). Помог школьный курс математики. И обратите внимание, что там не используются тригонометрические функции, квадраты и корни, а используется *производная*, что приводит к операциям сложения и битового сдвига.

Comment: "... он был разработан Джеком Элтоном Брезенхэмом в компании IBM в 1962 году". ([Алгоритм Брезенхэма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B0))

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy хорошо, что сейчас есть доступные источники информации. 30 лет назад (мы с вами ровесники) я просто не знал ни о Брезенхэме, ни о его алгоритме.

Comment: Тогда была "Техническая книга", в ней некоторое количество переводных книг по программированию.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy возможно, именно там я тогда купил очень захватывающую книгу С. Н. Баранова и Н. Р. Ноздрунова "Язык ФОРТ и его реализации".

Comment: А я купил Лео Броуди "Начальный курс программирования на языке ФОРТ".